# Compiling new type in PowerShell v2 - Cookie Aware WebClient

Tags: c#, powershell, webclient, powershell-2.0

I am trying to compile a "[cookie aware](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html)" version of the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class - but I can't seem to get over some of the hurdles of using the Add-Type cmdlet added in PowerShell v2. Here is the code I am trying to compile:

```
PS C:\> $def = @"
public class CookieAwareWebClient : System.Net.WebClient
{
  private System.Net.CookieContainer m_container = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
  protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri address)
  {
    System.Net.WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    if (request is System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    {
      (request as System.Net.HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = m_container;
    }
    return request;
  }
}
"@

PS C:\> Add-Type -TypeDefinition $def
```

It can't seem to find the CookieContainer type can't be found (though it is fully qualified...) - clearly I am blind on something.

**Edit:** Updated the sample code to be correct and copy-n-pasteable, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second reference to `CookieContainer` with the constructor expression is fully qualified.  The first reference, when declaring the field `m_container` is not.  Make both fully qualified so Powershell can find them

```
private System.Net.CookieContainer m_container = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was blind but couldn't see it!