# POST request with PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have got problem, I need to download graphics from next site
http://www.kakioka-jma.go.jp/cgi-bin/plot/plotSetNN.pl?lang=en

I am using PowerShell, I need to create POST request to Plot the image (see Plot button). The problem that I do now know how it's can be done in PowerShell. Before I used function 'System.Net.WebClient' for downloading, and created url for it with

I googled and find how POST request may be done in C#, and I tried to built them in one script. http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?2ppnztfqx3we
But it's not working, it's even do not print "Hello World", and I do not know how to get it's work.

But the main question - not get this code to work, but to find the easiest way to load that graphics, and it would be good if it would on Powershell.

I have seen "Http Rest" script, but it's to hard even to understand does it do what I need, I even do not talk about to modificate it's for my work. I need the simplest way, because my knowledge in programming it now good.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a series a while back on Splatting (a language technique in PowerShell V2).  The last item in the series provides a wrapper on the Net.WebClient class that makes it easier to send requests via Post.

The blog explains a lot about how the client object works, and you can read that if you want:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/22/make-windows-powershell-your-web-client.aspx

Or you can download the script directly from the Script Center Repository:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/7e7b6bf2-d067-48c3-96b3-b38f26a1d143

Hope this Helps,

Comment: Wonderful! I used your script in conjunction with this [cookie-aware WebClient example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261479/compiling-new-type-in-powershell-v2-cookie-aware-webclient). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like curl could be useful for you. It will deal with the trickier aspects of posting data to a web service.

I've used it myself to download text and parse through it with PowerShell. I had a batch file to call curl, the batch file was called from a powershell script. Sounds the long way around but it worked quickly and I didnl't have to put much time in!

I'm on my phone and don't have any examples here, if you interested I can have a look for them later.

HTH,
Matt